# Modifying web.config with powershell in Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I need to add the following to my published web.config;

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

that I am publishing with Asp.Net Core 2, however, it doesnt seem to be working;

```
$webConfig = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName + "\Bemfeito.Services.WebApi\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\PubTmp\Out\web.config"
$doc = (gc $webConfig) -as [Xml]

$moduleNode = $doc.CreateElement("modules")
$moduleNode.SetAttribute("runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests", "false")
$removeNode = $moduleNode.CreateElement("remove")
$removeNode.SetAttribute("name","WebDAVModule")
$moduleNode.AppendChild($removeNode)

$doc.configuration.system.webServer.AppendChild($moduleNode)

$doc.Save($webConfig)
```

(I am adding this as a prepublish option on my webdeploy) I think it has something to do with not grabbing and/or commiting the saves correctly? can someone please advise me on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I think the issue is with loading the web.config file as I have debugged the script using and have tried `gc web.config`, `get-content web.config`, `gc "$pwd\web.config"`, `Resolve-Path "web.config"` and `Resolve-Path web.config` (the web.config is in the same directory as a test when i run the script) Also I am using Visual Studio powershell tools i.e. right click and execute script on the .ps1 file

Comment: however is I use a full path i.e. `C:\\.....\web.config` this works? any idea on using the current working directory?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've literally just managed to get the xml to now load. It now doesnt seem to be adding the xml? I've updated the code to match what I have currently. Now it doesn tseem to be adding to the node tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a number of issues with appending to the node but the main one turned out to be the fact I was appending to `configuration.system.webServer.AppendChild`. In fact this should have been `configuartion.'system.webServer'.AppendChild`

For reference my full script is;

```
$webConfig = (Get-Item -Path ".\").FullName + 

"\Services.WebApi\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\PubTmp\Out\web.config"
$doc = (gc $webConfig) -as [Xml]

$moduleNode = $doc.CreateElement("modules")
$moduleNode.SetAttribute("runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests", "false")


$removeNode = $doc.CreateElement("remove")
$removeNode.SetAttribute("name","WebDAVModule")
$moduleNode.AppendChild($removeNode)

$doc.configuration.'system.webServer'.AppendChild($moduleNode)

$doc.Save($webConfig)
```